# How do you ensure that a thread is freed when using a threaded queue in Delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Me again, hopefully with more specific threading question.

I note that if I run the fine demos that Chris Rolliston provides here:

http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2011/05/06/using-tmonitor-2/

with FastMM turned on to report memory leaks, that the threads themselves are leaked.

That's no problem for a small demo, but for my app, with tens of thousands of iterations of using the thread, it runs my humble 32-bit app out of memory.  (I can't compile for 64 bit because I'm using the 32-bit only CrossTalk).

How do you ensure that the thread is freed when used with a threaded queue?

**NEW CODE ADDED**

```
program SimpleThreadQueueConsole;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  FastMM4,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.SyncObjs,
  uPrimeThread in 'uPrimeThread.pas',
  uPrimeThreadRunner in 'uPrimeThreadRunner.pas';

var
  PR: TPrimeThreadRunner;

begin
  Randomize;
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  PR := TPrimeThreadRunner.Create;
  try
    PR.DoIt;
  finally
    PR.Free;
  end;

end.
```

uPrimeThread.pas

```
    unit uPrimeThread;

    interface

    uses
          System.Classes
        , Generics.Collections
        ;

    type

      TPrimeThread = class(TThread)
      private
        FOutQueue: TThreadedQueue<string>;
        FInQueue: TThreadedQueue<string>;
        function IsPrime(const NumberToCheck: integer): boolean;
      public
        constructor Create(aCreateSuspended: Boolean; aInQueue:  TThreadedQueue<string>; aOutQueue:  TThreadedQueue<string>);
        procedure Execute; override;
      end;

    implementation

    uses
          System.SysUtils
        , System.SyncObjs
        ;

    const
      MaxPrime = 999;


    { TPrimeThread }

    constructor TPrimeThread.Create(aCreateSuspended: Boolean; aInQueue, aOutQueue: TThreadedQueue<string>);
    begin
      inherited Create(aCreateSuspended);
      FOutQueue := aOutQueue;
      FInQueue := aInQueue;
      FreeOnTerminate := True;
    end;

    procedure TPrimeThread.Execute;
    var
      S: string;
      ThreadID: TThreadID;
      NumberToCheck: integer;
    begin

        ThreadID := TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID;
        FOutQueue.PushItem(Format('Thread %d started...', [ThreadID]));

        while (FInQueue.PopItem(S) = wrSignaled) do
        begin
          NumberToCheck := Random(MaxPrime);
          if IsPrime(NumberToCheck) then
          begin
            FOutQueue.PushItem(Format('%s using thread %d: %d is prime', [S, ThreadID, NumberToCheck]));
          end else
          begin
            FOutQueue.PushItem(Format('%s using thread %d: %d is NOT prime', [S, ThreadID, NumberToCheck]));
          end;
        end;
    end;

    function TPrimeThread.IsPrime(const NumberToCheck: Integer): boolean;
    // This is really bad on purpose to make the threads work a little harder
    var
      i: integer;
    begin
      Result := True;
      if NumberToCheck in [0, 1] then
      begin
        Result := False;
        Exit;
      end;

      for i := 2 to NumberToCheck - 1 do
      begin
        if NumberToCheck mod i = 0 then
        begin
          Result := False;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    end.
```

uPrimeThreadRunner.pas

```
unit uPrimeThreadRunner;

interface

uses
      System.SyncObjs

    , Generics.Collections
    , System.SysUtils
    , uPrimeThread
    ;

const
  ThreadCount = 4;

type
  TPrimeThreadRunner = class
  private
    FTotalThreads: TCountdownEvent;
    FInQueue, FOutQueue: TThreadedQueue<string>;
    FCurrentEntry: integer;
    procedure DrainTheQueue;
    procedure AddEntry;
  public
    ThreadArray: array[1..ThreadCount] of TPrimeThread;
    procedure DoIt;
  end;

implementation

const
  NumberOfEntries = 10;

procedure TPrimeThreadRunner.DrainTheQueue;
var
  S: string;
begin
  while FOutQueue.PopItem(S) = wrSignaled do
    WriteLn(S);
end;

procedure TPrimeThreadRunner.AddEntry;
var
  S: string;
begin
  Inc(FCurrentEntry);
  S := Format('Entry %d:', [FCurrentEntry]) ;
  FInQueue.PushItem(S);
end;


procedure TPrimeThreadRunner.DoIt;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  FCurrentEntry := 0;

  FTotalThreads := TCountdownEvent.Create(1);
  FInQueue := TThreadedQueue<string>.Create(10, 1000, 1000);
  FOutQueue := TThreadedQueue<string>.Create(10, 1000, 1000);
  for i := 1 to ThreadCount do
  begin
    FTotalThreads.AddCount;
    try
      ThreadArray[i] := TPrimeThread.Create(True, FInQueue, FOutQueue);
      ThreadArray[i].Start;
    finally
      FTotalThreads.Signal;
    end;
  end;


  for I := 1 to NumberOfEntries do
  begin
    AddEntry;
  end;
  DrainTheQueue;

  FTotalThreads.Signal;
  FTotalThreads.WaitFor;
  FTotalThreads.Free;




  FInQueue.Free;
  FOutQueue.Free;

  Readln;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Free the thread when you are done with it. Using a threaded queue? How exactly? A producer/consumer? Send a terminate job to the consumer. Free it when you are done.

Comment: I am using the threaded queue exactly like the demo I linked to above. In fact, as is, it leaks threads.  If I call free when I am done, then  the app locks up on the call to Free.

Comment: Off site link. Why can't the code be here? Simplified if necessary. Usually you signal the queue that it is terminated and then all the consumers respond to that signal by quitting. Wait for them all to be signalled. Perhaps by destroying them.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing the loop in the thread doesn't check to see if the thread's been terminated. That loop will keep going on and on and on unless you either explicitly exit the loop or forcibly terminate the thread (which isn't advised).

Comment: A little debugging information wouldn't hurt here.  The anonymous worker threads in your example code spit out status messages - do you see the `Thread %d is terminating` messages?  Anonymous threads are `FreeOnTerminate` threads by default.  If they're not being freed then it's because they haven't completed their work yet.  If that's the case then this question should rather be : *Why are my worker threads stuck?*

Comment: Okay, fair enough -- why are my worker thread stuck?  ;-)

Comment: It was a rhetorical question.  The idea is that you put a breakpoint after the while loop and tell us what happens.

Comment: I can tell you that -- it never gets there.  Which means that the threads are never getting stopped.  But if I put "While not terminated" in there, and then actually call terminated on the threads with the containing object is destroyed, they still are leaked.

Comment: Ok, but now the code (which we still can't see) is changing.  Are you doing this before or after freeing `FThreadsActive`?  Throwing an exception in your `finally` block would introduce new problems.  Again, I think this question needs a lot more debugging information.

Comment: Added the code.  This version freezes when it is done.

Comment: Dependance of Spring.Collections, hmm lots of code to install. Can you decouple this from the question? BTW, have you tried using Delphi TThreadedQueue? Since XE2, upd4 it is fairly stable.

Comment: Oops.  I'll post similar code using TThreadedQueue, because it behaves the same way.

Comment: Posted new code with TThreadedQueue.

Comment: One more note:  Runs fine on XE6, but we use XE3 here at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your code, I can replicate it in XE3 and XE6.

The critical error is here:

```
for I := 1 to NumberOfEntries do
  begin
    AddEntry;
  end;
DrainTheQueue;  // <-- All threads may not be ready when this call finish

FTotalThreads.Signal;  // This makes nothing
FTotalThreads.WaitFor; // This makes nothing
FTotalThreads.Free;    // This makes nothing

FInQueue.Free;         // You may now free a queue in operation
FOutQueue.Free;        // You may now free a queue in operation
```

You can't rely on `DrainTheQueue` to collect all items until the threads are done.
When freeing the queues while one or more primethreads are running, the threads will operate on freed objects.

The easiest way to syncronize the finish of the threads, is to finish them with an empty string.

Call this before `DrainTheQueue`:

```
for i := 1 to ThreadCount do
  FInQueue.PushItem('');
```

And change the PrimeThread.Execute like this:

```
procedure TPrimeThread.Execute;
var
  S: string;
  ThreadID: TThreadID;
  NumberToCheck: integer;
begin

  ThreadID := TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID;
  FOutQueue.PushItem(Format('Thread %d started...', [ThreadID]));
  try
    while NOT Terminated do
    begin
      if (FInQueue.PopItem(S) = wrSignaled) then
      begin
        if (S = '') then  // Stop executing 
          Exit;
        NumberToCheck := Random(MaxPrime);
        if IsPrime(NumberToCheck) then
        begin
          FOutQueue.PushItem(Format('%s using thread %d: %d is prime', [S, ThreadID, NumberToCheck]));
        end else
        begin
          FOutQueue.PushItem(Format('%s using thread %d: %d is NOT prime', [S, ThreadID, NumberToCheck]));
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FOutQueue.PushItem(Format('Thread %d ended ...', [ThreadID]));
  end;
end;
```

You should also pass the `FTotalThreads` object to the worker threads and let them do the signal when they finish executing.
`DrainTheQueue` must be called after `FTotalThreads.Waitfor`.

Comment: YES!  Thank you so much.  This solved my problem of the leaking threads.  Yay!  I'm very grateful that you took the time.

Comment: My pleasure. One final note, when creating the queues with such a limited depth (and a small push timeout), you may be struck by losing items you want to push. With an infinite push timeout and the handshake procedure in my answer, it should be good though.

Comment: Correction, an infinite push time combined with handshake in a depth limited queue may cause a deadlock. I always have at least one thread draining the queue to prevent this situation, or a large enough queue.